# Oracle SQL - search for entries inside the same month but with different start/end dates

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I want to query for all entries in the table 'unique_delivery_locations' where 'transaction_identifier' is the same, and we are within the same month. The only difference should be in 'delivery_start_date' and 'delivery_end_date'. These could be different within the same month, some will start at the beginning of the month, and some in the middle.

I tried the following sequel, but I got the error:

> ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier

```
SELECT *
FROM unique_delivery_locations
WHERE transaction_identifier IN (
        SELECT transaction_identifier
        FROM unique_delivery_locations
        WHERE MONTH(delivery_start_date) = MONTH(delivery_end_date)
        GROUP BY transaction_identifier
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(delivery_start_date)) > 1
        );
```

Comment: I think you need to extract month in oracle: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E)

Comment: I.e. the ANSI/ISO SQL way!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want all the records from `unique_delivery_locations` when `delivery_start_date` is the same month as `delivery_end_date`.

Given that your delivery dates are in string format, we need to convert them, to `date` format first.

Try the code below:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    unique_delivery_locations t1
WHERE
    trunc(to_date(t1.delivery_start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm') = trunc(to_date(t1.delivery_end_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm')
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It throws an error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: is your `delivery_start_date` in `date` format? sounds like it's a `varchar`

Comment: Yes, delivery_start_date is in format 'varchar2/byte'

Comment: Can you provide an example how one row from `delivery_start_date` looks like?

Comment: Yes, for example, this one: 2023-09-30

Comment: I added `to_date` function, so the `varchar` dates would be converted to `date` format